# MYSQL QUERY LEFT JOIN ;

Tags: mysql, left-join

Sql lose the first row in my query

This is my query

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM bill  LEFT JOIN bstock on bstock.Buy_Stock_ID = bill.Buy_Stock_ID
LEFT JOIN product on product.Product_ID = bstock.Product_ID
LEFT JOIN customer on customer.Customer_ID = bstock.Customer_ID WHERE Bill_ID = $Bill_ID";
```

Comment: To which table does the `Bill_ID` column belong?

Comment: What do you mean by "lose the first row"? A row is missing from the result set that you expect to be there?

Comment: add some table data and expected results in there and we can help ya out :)

Comment: Bill_ID belong to bill table

Comment: When I used this code in phpmyadmin to query data, the results is complete but when I used in php it lose the first row data  exp. at  Bill_ID 004 have  5 data row data i got 4 the first row data missing in php. sorry in my english.